# Update specific rows in LINQ to SQL result set

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a page with a form on it and needs a range of dates. Thus I've placed a number of textboxes on the page into which users can type dates. When the user clicks the save button I want to trigger a LINQ update to the SQL Server...all the rows already exist, so I'm just updating existing data. How can I do this?
For example, lets say my table looks like this:

```
Column Names: Description dateValue
Column Values:
               Birthdate   1/1/1990
               Anniversary 1/10/1992
               Death       1/1/1993
```

I want to do something like this:

```
hupdate.Description("Birthdate").dateValue = TextBox1.Text
hupdate.Description("Anniversary").dateValue = TextBox2.Text
hupdate.Description("Death").dateValue = TextBox3.Text
hconfig.SubmitChanges()
```

Is there a way to do this with LINQ?

Comment: What, you want to use LINQ to SQL like typed Datasets? *shudders*

Comment: I assume when you say "LINQ" you mean "LINQ to SQL"?

Comment: @John Saunders - yes, I mean LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @Jon Limjap - I'm open to alternative methods for accomplishing the same end result.

Comment: thanks, I thought so, but keep in mind, there are other things with "LINQ" in the name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that with only LINQ. However, there are other ways to achieve that like:

- if you use Entity Framework you can use LINQ to query the data, then change the entities (within your c# code) and update the DB via them.
- Create a stored procedure that updates the data, according to your description this stored procedure doesn't seem like a complicated one.